# WORDPRESS: Slider with Image, Caption & Excerpt from custom fields, of the same post

Tags: wordpress, slideshow, custom-fields

Good Morning and Seasons Greetings! I am looking for help. I am trying to create a custom post, single page template where I want to embed a slider that fetches images, title and excerpt from the data of the same post. Let me describe the problem I seek help for.

The BACKGROUND Info 
1) I have created a custom Post Type called "HPC Products"
2) It is linked with Custom Taxonomy called "HPC Product Categories"
3) The custom fields group for HPC Product includes Key Highlight 1, Key Highlight 2, Key Highlight 3 (all 3 as Single text fields) it also has fields called Product Image 1, Product Image 2, Product Image 3 (All 3 Image fields) , there are some other fields too such as title, features etc,
4) I have made a Custom Content Template for the Single-HPC-Product.

THE GOAL (Which I am not able to achieve)
Within the single-hpc-product page, I have the title and tagline followed by product description.Under that I want to have a slider with 3 slides.

Slide 1 – Should fetch Prod Image 1, The title of Key Highlight 1 and the Details of Highlight 1
Slide 2 – Should fetch Prod Image 2, The title of Key Highlight 2 and the details of Highlight 2
Slide 3 – Should fetch Prod Image 3, The title of Key Highlight 3 and the details of Highlight 3.

I have searched a lot of the forum strings, I have tried more than 25 different attempts at views and templates with different options such as Post is Parent, Post is Child, – Template is slider, template is custom display etc etc, But for some reason I am not getting success.

I really would be grateful if you could help me out by guiding me with simple steps to do this, I am a newbie with no knowledge or experience in php or coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create your custom fields. If not use get_post_meta() instead of get_field()

First you need to find a slider that match with your requirements. After you found one look at it's markup. Imagin it's look like following code ,

```
<div id="slider-main">
   <div class="slide">
       <img src="images/img1.png" />
       <span class="caption-1">Key Highlight</span>
       <p class="caption-2">Key highlight details</p>
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
       <img src="images/img2.png" />
       <span class="caption-1">Key Highlight</span>
       <p class="caption-2">Key highlight details</p>
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
       <img src="images/img3.png" />
       <span class="caption-1">Key Highlight</span>
       <p class="caption-2">Key highlight details</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

your template file look like this,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div id="main">

    <div id="slider-main">

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('product_img1'); ?>" />
            <span class="caption-1"><?php echo get_field('key_highlight1'); ?></span>
            <p class="caption-2"><?php echo get_field('highlight_details1'); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('product_img2'); ?>" />
            <span class="caption-1"><?php echo get_field('key_highlight2'); ?></span>
            <p class="caption-2"><?php echo get_field('highlight_details2'); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="<?php echo get_field('product_img3'); ?>" />
            <span class="caption-1"><?php echo get_field('key_highlight3'); ?></span>
            <p class="caption-2"><?php echo get_field('highlight_details3'); ?></p>
        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dhanuka. I shall try this out and come back with the results. :-)